# Async await issue in conditional statements

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I've recently started using async await functionality in C# and face a problem. sorry if it is basic. I'm new to async methods.

Considering having threeasync methods:

```
public async Task DoFirstJob () { /// some works to do }
public async Task DoSecondJob() { /// some works to do }
public async Task DoTheJob() {
    await DoFirstJob();
    await DoSecondJob();
}
```

It works fine. But the issue comes when I want to call the DoFirstJob() method under certain conditions like:

```
public async Task DoTheJob() {
    if (IsConditionTrue()) {
        await DoFirstJob();
    }
    await DoSecondJob();
}
```

Now the DoSecondJob() doesn't wait for the DoFirstJob() to be completed. I really need to know what the problem is and how to fix it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you debug the code to check if your condition is true? so that DoFirstJob() gets called.

Comment: Sure. I'm not saying the DoFirstJob() won't be called at all. It seems to me that the two methods run simultaneously.

Comment: Replace IsConditionTrue() by true, and try debugging..? Or make IsConditionTrue() return true always and debug..

Comment: Please provide code that demonstrates problem (preferably ready to copy/paste to LinqPad or console app). Make sure to provide clear way to detect your case (like counters/WriteLine ). Right now your "doesn't wait for the DoFirstJob() to be completed" does not look very convincing.

Comment: I'm not seeing any problems: [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0msxgw).

Comment: @user3530012, I return true from DoFirstJob in the condition and it gave the expected output that first called DoFirstJob and then DoSecondJob, There might be something in your code causing the unexpected results. Sharing your code could help identifying the problem.